# Using File I/O to traverse directory in windows

Tags: java, windows, file, io, nullpointerexception

I'm writing a program that uses File I/O to traverse through a directory given by the user and then adds the directories to a generic linked list. The program I wrote works perfectly on Ubuntu, but does not work when I try to use it on Windows. Its a pretty long program but this is the part that I think is having issues:

```
private Node<Item> currentNode = new Node<Item>();

public void traverse(File fileObject)
{
    File allFiles[] = fileObject.listFiles();

    for(File aFile: allFiles){
        System.out.println(aFile.getName()); /* debugging */
        recursiveTraversal(aFile); /* Line 34 */
    }
}


public void recursiveTraversal(File fileObject){
    Node<Item> newNode = new Node<Item>();
    currentNode.addChild(newNode);
    currentNode = newNode;
    if (fileObject.isDirectory()){
        newNode.setData(new Item());

        File allFiles[] = fileObject.listFiles();
        for(File aFile : allFiles){ /* This is line 48 */
            recursiveTraversal(aFile);
        }            

    }else if (fileObject.isFile()){
        newNode.setData(new Item());
    }           
    currentNode = newNode.getParent();
}
```

When I use it on Linux I can give it something like `/home/matt/Documents` and it works, but when I try on windows using `G:\\Users\\Matt\\Documents` it errors out. The print statement I threw in actually prints out files in the folder, but something with the rest of the program messes up:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at FileTraverse.recursiveTraversal(FileTraverse.java:48)
at FileTraverse.traverse(FileTraverse.java:34)
at DirectoryMain$ClickAction.actionPerformed(DirectoryMain.java:103)
    ...
```

Theres a lot of errors afterwards that have to do with the Swing GUI this program is running off of but I don't think that has to do with anything.

EDIT: Added in line numbers that correspond with the trace.

Comment: Where does `currentNode` object get created before you do - `currentNode.addChild(newNode);`?

Comment: Somewhere up at the top of my class as a global variable.

Comment: Can you add that snippet on how you are defining `currentNode`? What does line 48 in FileTraverse.java have?

Comment: I have added in the currentNode line as well as added comments next to the lines the errors refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is that you are hitting a directory which for some reason windows will not allow you to view.  listFiles() is most likely returning null in this instance.

Comment: This does seem possible as the program seems to be working for other certain directories..

Comment: Would also explain why it's only an issue on Windows. Maybe try running the app again with elevated rights. I.e. "run as administrator".

Answer (score 3):

From the Javadoc of [File.listFile()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) (emphasis added):

> Returns: An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. **Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.**

You'll need to cope with null returns from `listFiles()`, unfortunately with the `java.io.File` API there is no way to find out exactly what error occurred.

If you are using Java 7, you can use the [DirectoryStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) class instead:

```
private void recursiveTraversal(Path path)
throws IOException
{
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) 
    {
        for (Path entry : stream) 
        {
            //Do something with entry
            doSomething(entry);

            if (Files.isDirectory(entry))
                recursiveTraversal(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

The difference being that `newDirectoryStream()` can throw an `IOException` (or a subclass such as `AccessDeniedException` that gives information about why the call failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a `NullPointerException` on line 48, it must mean the `allFiles` array you've obtained is `null`. According to the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) for that method, this should only occur if the File you're calling it on is not a directory or some IO error occurs. It is a bit odd since you do check if it's a directory in the `if`. Maybe there's some access issue on OS level, regarding permissions.

You might want to look into using `FileFilter`s or maybe stuff from the `java.nio.file` package. I believe the latter makes traversing directories easier.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `traverse()` and `recursiveTraversal()` is a little
strange to me; when would you use `traverse()`? What role does it play
that `recursiveTraversal()` doesn't already do? Sure, `traverse()` assumes
it is working with a directory, but `recursiveTraversal()` already handles
directories well.

There's all the fiddling about with `Item`s in `recursiveTraversal()`, but
since they don't *do* anything here, it's hard to spot the utility. :)

```
public void traverse(File fileObject)
{
    File allFiles[] = fileObject.listFiles();

    for(File aFile: allFiles){
        System.out.println(aFile.getName()); /* debugging */
        recursiveTraversal(aFile);
    }
}


public void recursiveTraversal(File fileObject){
    Node<Item> newNode = new Node<Item>();
    currentNode.addChild(newNode);
    currentNode = newNode;
    if (fileObject.isDirectory()){
        newNode.setData(new Item());

        File allFiles[] = fileObject.listFiles();
        for(File aFile : allFiles){
            recursiveTraversal(aFile);
        }            

    }else if (fileObject.isFile()){
        newNode.setData(new Item());
    }           
    currentNode = newNode.getParent();
}
```

I would probably move the `newNode.setData(new Item());` *above* the
`isDirectory()` check to make it clear that `newNode` has a new `Item`
added to it no matter if the current `fileObject` is a file or directory:

```
public void recursiveTraversal(File fileObject){
    Node<Item> newNode = new Node<Item>();
    currentNode.addChild(newNode);
    currentNode = newNode;
    newNode.setData(new Item());
    if (fileObject.isDirectory()){
        File allFiles[] = fileObject.listFiles();
        for(File aFile : allFiles){
            recursiveTraversal(aFile);
        }            
    }else if (fileObject.isFile()){
        /* must do _something_ with files */
    }           
    currentNode = newNode.getParent();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is true. Thanks for the advice. Sorry for my messy code. I have just started learning data structures and I will try to get the unnecessary stuff out as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying something similar on Windows and the program would crash and return a nullPointerException as soon the program tried traversing a directory where the security permissions had restricted access.

Unless you need the program to add secure/hidden/system folders, simply handle the error using a try catch clause.

```
public static void dive(File file, int level){    
    try{
        for(File x : file.listFiles())
            if(x.isDirectory() && !x.isHidden())
                dive(x);
     }catch(NullPointerException e){
        // Do nothing..
     }
 }
```

This should traverse all user directories